# class containing a generic type of a child

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is there any possible way that a generic type can be used to contain a child of a base class.

From the assignment given to me, I am to create something similar to the following in structure.

```
template <class T>
class Fruit {
  private:
    int count;
    int location_id;
    T type;
  public:
    virtual void displayInfo();
};

class Apple : private Fruit<Apple> {
  private:
    int variety;
  public:
    void displayInfo() {
        printf("Location %i has %i of %s in stock", location_id, count, variety);
    }
};

Fruit<Apple> appleinventory[SIZE];
```

Basically, I think you can't have a template generic type be the same as a derived class.  Am I wrong?  Is there something similar that would possibly work?

Update:
For the assignment, I believe we are to use inheritance to show use of virtual functions.  I've updated the code above.  I think this would work, but does NOT need templates to be successful.  We have not covered any advanced, redundant inheritance methods in class.

Comment: Why do you think this is the wrong way to go?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It is completely unclear to me what your example is trying to accomplish. You can't inherit from `Fruit` because `Fruit` is not a class. You'd need to inherit from `Fruit<Something>`. If your intent is to let `Apple` be a subclass of `Fruit<Apple>`, you'll run into problems, because then an instance of `Apple` would have a member of type `Apple`, which can't work unless you change the member of type `T` to be a pointer or reference.

Comment: I didn't know syntactically if inheriting from a template was correct.  But yes, I've been asked to have Fruit be a template, which will be instantiated with Apple as T.  I've also been asked to have Apple inherit Fruit.  So I've basically been asked to have `Apple : private Fruit<Apple>`.

Comment: yes that will work, if you fix your code - there is not much point in having the `base` class template try to encapsulate the `derived` class if your goal is to have `derived` inherit from `base<derived>` - redundant, yes?  What you then intend to do with `derived` is the interesting question.

Comment: in my example, which is an adaptation of the assignment, `Fruit<Apple> appleinventory[]` would store information on apple inventories at different locations.  But we haven't covered the use of derived and inherited classes in a redundant fashion.  I think the assignment isn't well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly fine, in principle.

Read up about [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) for more info on usage of derived class as the instantiating type in a class template that is its base, esp the example about static polymorphism which should look 'curiously' familiar.

```
template <class Derived> struct Base
{
    void interface()
    {
        // ...
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
        // ...
    }

    static void static_func()
    {
        // ...
        Derived::static_sub_func();
        // ...
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void implementation();
    static void static_sub_func();
};
```

Comment: This is interesting and shows it can happen.  However, the way it was described to me won't work in this manner...

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring questions of why you want to do this....you can get some of the way by doing this following:

```
template <class T> class Fruit 
{
private:
    int count;
    int location_id;
    T* type;
};

class Apple : private Fruit<Apple> 
{
private:
    int seeds;
    bool red;
};

Fruit<Apple> appleinventory[SIZE];
```

Note the T* type is now a pointer to Apple rather than an instance of Apple.